# Terminal Regex Syntax

Tags: regex, bash, macos

I'm trying to test a string from a user to see if its either a positive integer or decimal. I currently have:

`if ! [[ "$varSize" =~ ^[0-9]+(?:$|\.[0-9]+) ]]
        then
            echo "SIZE CAN ONLY CONTAIN NUMBERS"
fi`

But i get line errors so think something is wrong with my regex formatting. The regex work fine on regexr so guess its a bash thing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Bash doesn't support the PCRE regex dialect. Regexr (and a number of similar online tools) is not a good tester for Bash regex.

Comment: Ah. Thought it might be something like that. I don't know bash very well so any help translating the expression to something bash friendly would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

varSize="12.a3"
echo $varSize
re='^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'

if [[ "${varSize}" =~ $re ]]
   then
       echo "SIZE CONTAINS NUMBERS only"
   else
       echo "SIZE is not a number"
fi
```

you can play out with this little script to adjust it further to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. Works a treat! Any reason you put the expression in a variable first?

Comment: @ChrisBarrett To avoid some oddities in the way bash parses regular expressions that *aren't* coming from variables. See [the Unix&Linux question, "How does storing the regular expression in a shell variable avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382054/how-does-storing-the-regular-expression-in-a-shell-variable-avoid-problems-with)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBarrett for clarifications,

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks both.